# How to prevent Samsung wallet from intercepting digital key setup, and do it in Google wallet instead

Tags: google-wallet, samsung-pay

I use Google wallet for payments on my s23 ultra. I would like to add a digital car key, but the Samsung wallet app keeps hijacking the setup process. The Samsung wallet app is not even installed. How do I get it to stop interrupting and allow Google wallet to handle the key registration?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. "*The Samsung wallet app is not even installed.*" on my Samsung M12 (and I believe on other Samsung devices), Samsung Pay/Wallet is a built-in/system app. Couldn't you find it, even on Settings - Apps?

Comment: @AndrewT. Thank you :) If I uninstall the app, then no, it does not appear, but interestingly, 'Samsung Wallet Digital Key' does appear, and cannot be uninstalled or disabled.